# How to save img into csv using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I'm searching on web how to paste image(not url to csv), but there is no one good answer for me.

[Want to do like at image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykmMF.jpg)

Right now using method like that:

```
data = []
def scrape_data(iterator):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('1.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for i in iterator:
        url = f'https://kream.co.kr/api/p/tabs/all/?cursor={i}&&request_key=7844c102-1f44-4bc5-9d4f-9a5be38b04dd'
        r  = requests.get(url, headers=headers,cookies=cookies)
        data_json = r.json()
        print(f'Page no.{i}')
        print(r)

        try:
            for idx,item in enumerate(data_json['items']):
                eng_name = item['product']['release']['name']
                orig_name = item['product']['release']['translated_name']
                img_url = item['product']['release']['image_urls'][0]
                img = Image.open(requests.get(img_url, stream = True).raw)

                img.save(f'{i*idx}.png')

                worksheet.set_column('F:F', width=50)

                worksheet.insert_image(f'F{i*idx}', rf"{i*idx}.png", {'x_scale': 0.1, 'y_scale': 0.1})
                model_num = item['product']['release']['style_code']
                model_num_w_dash = item['product']['release']['style_code'].replace('-', '')
                brand = item['product']['brand']['name']
                id = item['product']['release']['id']
                links = f'https://kream.co.kr/products/{id}' 
                data.append([eng_name,orig_name,model_num,model_num_w_dash,brand,links]) 
        except:
            continue  
    workbook.close()
    

def save(data):
    header = ['English Name', 'Original Name','Model Number', 'Model number(without dash)', 'Brand', 'Link']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=header)
    df.to_csv('example.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```

This method has some errors and don't look clear. I have some empty columns and error like that:
UserWarning: Cannot insert image at (-1, 5).
warn('Cannot insert image at (%d, %d).' % (row, col))
And I has 2 different files: 1 for images and 1 for other data, I want all in one.

Thank you!

Comment: For start - define your goal right - you want to insert image in a cell in excel file, not csv,

Comment: It doesn't matter,excel or csv

Comment: Of course it matters, csv is pure text format, уou can not embed images

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pandas supports what you are trying to do as it is just for numerical data. What you are need is xlsxwriter

```pip install XlsxWriter````

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('my_xlsx_file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.insert_image('B2', 'image.png')
workbook.close()
```

[Reference](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html)

In your save method, if you must use excel:

```
import pandas as pd

def save(data):
    cols = ["header1", "header2", ...]
    writer = pd.read_excel("my_xlsx_file.xlsx", header=cols)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.close()
```

Pandas [excel reader](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#:%7E:text=Read%20an%20Excel%20file%20into,a%20local%20filesystem%20or%20URL.),
[xlsx wirter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)